# Match all fields of an array using a regex

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a field that contains an array with three values that are either set to null or true:

```
"evidence": [true, null, true]
```

I want to a make a query that will match a couple different combinations of these values such as:

```
"evidence": [true,true,null]
"evidence": [true,true,true]
```

I am currently doing this by doing two different queries. Can I match an array with a regex like:

```
"evidence": [true,true,/true|null/]
```

My attempts at doing this have returned zero results.

Comment: Regular expressions strictly match strings only, so your boolean and null values cannot be matched. Not sure of your use case here due to how you have presented your question, but the new [set operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/) for the aggregation framework may be of use to you.

Comment: why don't you just read the 3rd value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query object, you can refer to specific elements in your `evidence` array by their numeric index.  If you combine this ability with an `$in` operator to match one of a set of values, you can do the query like this:

In the shell:

```js
db.test.find({
    'evidence.0': true,
    'evidence.1': true,
    'evidence.2': {$in: [true, null]}
})
```

In Python:

```
db.test.find({
    'evidence.0': True,
    'evidence.1': True,
    'evidence.2': {'$in': [True, None]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is with set operations, as was noted.  For a single field in that array, you can do something like:

```
container['evidence'][index] in set([True, False])
```

If you are trying to match all of the fields in the array, you could do something like making a list of those sets of acceptable values, then doing something like:

```
query = (set([True]), set([True, False]), set([None]))
all(x in query[i] for i, x in enumerate(container['evidence'][index]))
```

This construct will check each one in a row and if one fails, it will bail out with a False.  Without more info about what you're trying to do, it's hard to improve on these general comments.

Comment: Note that in later versions of python, you can use just use set constructions like `{True, False}` rather than using the set constructor keyword.